# Use of window.location.href in crosswalk

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

I use [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) 5.34.104.5 to build Android app.

After executing

```
location.href = '/another_page.html'
```

in index.html, which is a entry point defined by manifest.json,
empty alert pops up and blank page appears.

`another_page.html` is located in the same directory as index.html 
(i.e. it is in apk file whose path is `assets/www/another_page.html` relative to apk's root)
and is not served over network.

How can I achieve intended location transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo in "asserts/www/another_page.html", it should be assets, right? I can do the same thing with changing location.href to load another page.

EDIT: If you are using make_apk.py to package your app, you can pass "--enable-remote-debugging" to turn on remote debugging for your app. Once the app is launched on your device, open 'chrome://inspect' in Chrome browser running on the host machine, and inspect the page to directly execute "window.location.href=xxx" in console, and try to fix your problem. See https://crosswalk-project.org/#wiki/Remote-Debugging-on-Android for details.

Comment: It was a typo. I edited it. If I set `location.href="file:///android_asset/www/another_page.html"`, it worked. But, Do I really have to set `location.href` in this way? it's a bit messy.

Comment: Ok, `location.href="another_page.html"` works. absolute path seems to case some trouble.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to set "location.href=/www/another_page.html" instead.